# turning switch off to ceiling fan/light does not immediately kill the light

Tags: light-fixture

This issue just started occurring in the last week or two. The fixture has been installed for ~18 mo with no issue.

The light gets brighter momentarily--maybe a 1/4 of a second then goes off very briefly, then lights again for a 1/2 sec, before finally going and stay off.

The bulbs are incandescent. The switch is a plain SPST--no dimmer, or 'smarts'

Ideas on cause?

Comment: a defective smart switch is one possible cause

Comment: What kind of switch? Smart? Dimmer? Timer? Model # if you can find it.

Comment: Just a regular ol' SPST switch. No dimmer, timer, or smarts.

Comment: Probably a defective switch, but also check for a couple of wires touching (or a wire touching the connecting screws of the switch).

Comment: That sounds like the way arc faults behave.   The light is in series with the arc.

Comment: Does this behavior still happen if the pullchains are used to disable the ceiling fan?

Comment: Same behavior with pull-chain. That eliminates the switch. Looks like the fixture itself is the culprit. Time for a new light kit.